# Loop with break or continue based on user input

Tags: node.js, loops, discord.js

I loosely know how to use a loop. I've used simple ones and understand how it works. However, I have a situation where I think a loop would be useful, but I'm not quite certain how to get the desired result. I am self-taught in javascript and I've tried poking around some other posts, but I don't recall seeing anything that helped in my case. This may very well be one of my gaps in understanding.

What I'd like this to do: This code is going to be taking the top card off a deck of cards for a TCG. Each card has a "type". I want the person to input a command into Discord like "!flipcard 10". I would like the bot to make a loop to flip cards off the top of the deck until 10 is reached OR a certain card type is flipped over. The card "types" I am working with are "action", "evo", "flip" and "hero". I only want the bot to react differently to the "Flip" card type. I have gotten working code to where I can do this if the user inputs !flipcard but does it one at a time. The maximum amount of cards that can ever be flipped is 34 cards or so, but this is less likely to happen than lower numbers.

I just wrote the code up from what I think I need to do, but I get stuck with not knowing exactly where to go next. So it isn't exactly functioning code yet. I do get an "illegal break statement" error currently, so I can't progress much more.

```
for (i = 0; i < damageToTake; i++) {
cardRemoved = deckAarray.shift()


//Bunch of stuff edited out for Embed mentioned below

    if (cardType == "Flip"){
       message.channel.send(flipEmbed)
       const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
       author.send(`You revealed a Flip card! Do you wish to use it? Please reply with 'yes' or 'no'.`).then((newmsg) => {
       newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
       max: 1,
        }).then((collected) => {

            reply = collected.first();

              if (reply.content == 'yes'){
                 console.log("Yes reply.")
                 break;
              } else if (reply.content == 'no'){
                 console.log("No reply")
                 } 
                })
            })
            } else if (cardType != "Flip"){
                message.channel.send(nonflipEmbed)
                continue;
            }
        }
    })
    }
```

Like I mentioned, the code isn't working to a point I can try it and get a problem because I am getting an "illegal break statement" error.

I think I am on the right track, but I'm uncertain how to make it work exactly how I'm hoping.

So, to conclude...

I would like this code to to the following:

1)User inputs command and specifies how many cards to flip over.
2)Loop should flip cards (displaying the correct embed based on card type)
3)When a "flip" card type is revealed, I would like the code to pause, essentially, to ask the author whether or not they would like to use the Flip card that was revealed. If yes, stop the loop. If no, continue the loop from where it left off until the desired number are flipped OR if another Flip card type is revealed.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: break statement is applicable if you have for or while loop. I do not see that in your code . There are only if else if statement.

Comment: @TanmayPatil Sorry about that, I didn't put a line break after the ``` to specify the start of the code. so it omitted the actual loop statement! Should be fixed now.

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-label-statement-a391cef4c556

Answer (score 0):

You've changed contexts -- as in you have two functions that know nothing about each other's control flow (e.g.: if/then, for loops, while loops, etc). They cannot influence each other in the way you're wanting. What you're doing is the equivalent of this pseudo code:

```
function printAllNumbers() {
  for(currentNumber : allNumbers) {
    printNumber(currentNumber);
  }
}

function printNumber(num) {
    print(num);
    break; // This won't work because it has no clue about for/loop in other func
}
```

printNumber is scoped so that it only knows what its own function (those 2 lines) are doing. It has no clue about the for/each in the printAllNumbers call, hence the error you're seeing.

And what I said above is only partially true -- you're actually maybe 2 functions deep at this point because you've called .then() and then after your .newMessage() call another .then(). You're reading the code sequentially, but you should try and look at it as branching off paths in this way:

```
for {
    call async functions and (.then) call these other functions
}
...some time passes
<branched off path> The other functions within .then(functions) get called
```

I recommend reading up on how asynchronous functions work, and also how promises work to better understand in what order your code will execute.

To do what you want, you'll need to write separate code to handle these scenarios:

1) Receiving the number of cards from user and just flat out looping through and printing those cards to chat

2) Receiving further input based on the user (will need to keep track of user) and the current state of their cards that have been flipped -- probably want to number the cards and have them send a command like USE 1 or DISCARD ALL

The code won't pause in the middle of your loop to wait for input, these each have to be different pieces of code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know a couple ways I could tackle #1 and get the maximum amount of cards that could be flipped, but then finding a way to iterate through each one, check the card type and ask the user what action to take IF the type is a "flip" type is where I'm not sure where to go on.  Jumping back into iterating through the number of cards that could be flipped is where I'm lost. If the person replies yes, the iteration COULD stop with the way this TCG goes, depends on the card and action of the person flipping them. Any further advice on how to tackle #2?

Comment: For #1, if you're handling user input already (someone can type !flip 10), it shouldn't be too hard to kick off a different function depending on the message content. If starts with !flip, you can make a function to handle flippingCards, and pass the user to it so it can do a lookup on their state. Same with other events, no? As for #2, I'm not as familiar with discord.js, but if it's javascript, you should be able to have a correctly scoped var that you shovel user state data into to store what stage they're at ("BEGIN" default state, "AWAITING_FLIP_SKIP" state, etc) and what cards are left.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible without code modification. The reason for this is that for loops are synchronous, while promises are not. This means that `.then()` will only be reached after the loop completes.

One way around this is to wrap everything inside an async function and run your loop in there. Then, use try-catch clauses to break out of the loop when needed. Consider the toy example below:

```
 ( async () => {
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        console.log('i:', i);

        try {
            const val = await randomPromise();
            console.log('should resolve and break!');
            console.log(val);
            break;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('moving on...');
        }
    }
})();


 function randomPromise() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        const val = Math.random();
        if (val > 0.9) {
            resolve(val);
        } else {
            reject(0);
        }
    })
 }
```